# Objective C Hpple to get commented element information

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-scraping, hpple

I'm starting my iPhone programming adventure, with a simple HTML scraping. I'm using the Hpple library to do the job, and I have a question...
Suppose I have the following html to parse...

```
<div>
    <div> A <!-- Comment 1 --></div>
    <div> B </div>
    <div> C <!-- Comment 2 --></div>
</div>
```

How can I retrieve the commented parts? They don't show up on the objects... I was checking the docs but there's nothing pointing to that direction.. (also googling "hpple comment" doesn't produce the best results...).

thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe look at using NSXMLParser? It seems to support comments according to the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Comments are not considered part of the content and are stripped out by pretty much all parsers except humans.

Similarly, you can't ask the parser to tell you how many spaces and newlines are between the first two `<div>` elements.

Comment: Well, I only asked because the library I use for Android makes it possible. :/

Comment: looks like NSXMLParser can notify it's delegate about comments, CDATA and others...